# announceForAccessibility doesn't work without Handler().postDelayed

Tags: android, accessibility-api

I have an `EditText` for user to input email and a `TextView` to show error but default is hidden and finally a submit button on the screen. We can't display error message using `TextInputLayout` because of the requirement coming from design.

What happen is when user clicks on submit button, we call `textview.announceForAccessibility("hello");` if email is invalid. This works if the green rect stays on submit button, but it doesn't always like that. If green rect is on `EditText`, talkback only describe the `EditText` and totally ignore the error message. However, if I add a second delay to it, it works. `new Handler().postDelayed(() -> textview.announceForAccessibility("hello"), 1000);`

I don't really understand why and how to solve the issue correctly.

Comment: Please show the code you have tried...

Comment: that's basically everything I've tried.